# Change filename when uploading array

Tags: php, postgresql, server-side

I am uploading a files to a folder, from there I am uploading the path of the files to a database, all executed using an array using PHP. Before the upload how can I change the uploaded file name to something random/unique?

PHP:

```html
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];







 
$conn_info = "host= port= dbname= user= password=";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_info) or die('could not connect:' . pg_last_error());
   echo"<br/>sucessful connection";
       

for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
        // get path
        $path = "uploads/".$name_array[$i];
        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        // Insert query 
        $query = "INSERT INTO example (path) VALUES ('".$path."') ;";
        pg_query($dbconn, $query);
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
} 
 
 echo "<br/> file uploaded to PostgreSQL";
 pg_close();

 ?>
```

Comment: use php's rename function.

Comment: @JacobMorgans remember to accept SO answers! It helps other users find solutions to similar questions, as well as rewarding those who take the time to help the OP ;)

Comment: @JustBaron apologies, will do thankyou!

Comment: You can either use the `rename()` function (after upload), or change the target file path of your `move_uploaded_file()` function, (during upload)